# How to get the first link using JSOUP?

Tags: java, android, string, jsoup

I want to use Jsoup to extract the first link on the google search results. For example, I search for "apple" on google. The first link I see is [www.apple.com/](http://www.apple.com/). How do I return the first link? I am currently able to extract all links using Jsoup:

```
       new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(sharedURL).get();
                String title = doc.title();
                Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
                stringBuilder.append(title).append("\n");
                for (Element link : links) {
                    stringBuilder.append("\n").append(" ").append(link.text()).append(" ").append(link.attr("href")).append("\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                stringBuilder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // set text
                    textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
Element firstLink = doc.select("a[href]").first();
```

It works for me. If you meant something else let us know. I checked the search results with the following and its a tough one to decipher as there are so many types of results that come back.. maps, news, ads, etc.

I tidied up the code a little with the use of java lambdas:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                String sharedUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=apple";
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(sharedUrl).get();
                String title = doc.title();
                Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
                Element firstLink = links.first();  // <<<<< NEW ADDITION
                stringBuilder.append(title).append("\n");
                for (Element link : links) {
                    stringBuilder.append("\n")
                            .append(" ")
                            .append(link.text())
                            .append(" ")
                            .append(link.attr("href"))
                            .append("\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                stringBuilder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }
            // replaced some of this for running/testing locally
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString()));
        }).start();
    }
```